# Python: Counting occurrences of List element within List

Tags: python, list, count

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of elements within a list, if such elements are also lists. The order is also important.

```
[PSEUDOCODE]

lst = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a'] ]
print( count(lst) )


> { ['a', 'b', 'c'] : 2, ['d', 'e', 'f']: 1, ['c', 'b', 'a']: 1 }
```

One important factor is that `['a', 'b', 'c'] != ['c', 'b', 'a']`

I have tried:

```
from collections import counter
print( Counter([tuple(x) for x in lst]) )
print( [[x, list.count(x)] for x in set(lst)] )
```

Which both resulted in `['a', 'b', 'c'] = ['c', 'b', 'a']`, one thing i didn't want

I also tried:

```
from collections import counter
print( Counter( lst ) )
```

Which only resulted in error; since `lists` can't be used as `keys` in `dicts`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: `tuple(['a', 'b', 'c']) == tuple(['c', 'b', 'a'])` gives me `False`

Comment: Since "lists can't be used as keys in dicts", your desired output is impossible; what do you want instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have `list` as a key to the `dict` because dictionaries only allows immutable objects as it's key. Hence you need to firstly convert your objects to tuple. Then you may use [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the count of each tuple as:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a'] ]

#            v to type-cast each sub-list to tuple
>>> Counter(tuple(item) for item in my_list)
Counter({('a', 'b', 'c'): 2, ('d', 'e', 'f'): 1, ('c', 'b', 'a'): 1})
```

Answer (score 6):

Lists are not hashable, but you can use tuples as a workaround:

```
l = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a'] ]
new_l = list(map(tuple, l))
final_l = {a:new_l.count(a) for a in new_l}
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c'): 2, ('d', 'e', 'f'): 1, ('c', 'b', 'a'): 1}
```

Or, if you really want to use lists, you can create a custom class to mimic the functionality of a dictionary hashing lists:

```
class List_Count:
    def __init__(self, data):
       new_data = list(map(tuple, data))
       self.__data = {i:new_data.count(i) for i in new_data}
    def __getitem__(self, val):
       newval = [b for a, b in self.__data.items() if list(a) == val]
       if not newval:
          raise KeyError("{} not found".format(val))
       return newval[0]
    def __repr__(self):
       return "{"+"{}".format(', '.join("{}:{}".format(list(a), b) for a, b in self.__data.items()))+"}"

l = List_Count([ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a'] ])
print(l)
print(l[['a', 'b', 'c']])
```

Output:

```
{['a', 'b', 'c']:2, ['d', 'e', 'f']:1, ['c', 'b', 'a']:1}
2
```

Comment: The tuple workaround is nice to get an almost one-liner solution!

Answer (score 6):

just use `collections.Counter` on some equivalent type but hashable: the `tuple`:

```
import collections

lst = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a'] ]

c = collections.Counter(tuple(x) for x in lst)

print(c)
```

result:

```
Counter({('a', 'b', 'c'): 2, ('d', 'e', 'f'): 1, ('c', 'b', 'a'): 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation with lists

```
l1 = [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["c", "b", "a"]]

def unique(l1):
    l2 = []
    for element in l1:
        if element not in l2:
            l2.append(element)
    return l2

l2 = unique(l1)
for element in l2:
    print(element, l1.count(element))
```

and if you want an dictionary from that you can just change the last part to

```
output = {element:l1.count(element) for element in unique(l1)}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Don't Use list as variable name.**

You can try this approach if you don't want to use any module :

```
list_1 = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a'] ]

track={}

for i in list_1:
    if tuple(i) not in track:
        track[tuple(i)]=1
    else:
        track[tuple(i)]+=1

print(track)
```

outoput:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c'): 2, ('d', 'e', 'f'): 1, ('c', 'b', 'a'): 1}
```

You can also use default dict:

```
list_1 = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a'] ]

track={}

import collections
d=collections.defaultdict(list)

for j,i in enumerate(list_1):
    d[tuple(i)].append(j)

print(list(map(lambda x:{x:len(d[x])},d.keys())))
```